# Sharepoint 2013:Save the Documents in repository and provide the reference in sharepoint document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document

I need help on the issue: When i upload the the document it need to save in the specified the local(or server) folder and the that reference should save in the Sharepoint document library.

we are going to upload more than 6 Millions documents every month.So we need to store in the fileserver(we don't want o use RBS).

Please let me know how to save the file in the folder and the reference(Or path) need to store in the Document Library.

Thanks for the help in advance

Thanks,
KK

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done this using Linkedtodocument Content type.Add a folder on the machine and linke it to the DOcumnent

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked the content type "link to a document?" [See this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3f2c34cc-5686-4e03-ba26-092aaa29ff33/link-from-document-library-to-unc-path?forum=sharepointadminlegacy).

Comment: Thanks for the Link , I am able to add the UNC path through sharepoint,but I need to update the Document library using Linke to document.I can upload the file as file.aspx,but Not able to update URL and Docpath.

Comment: Are you willing to pay? http://www.avepoint.com/assets/pdf/doc6/DocAve_Connector_for_SharePoint_File_Share_Integration.pdf We use Avepoint and tey have great support.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Page View Web part to a page and point it to your file share. Then users can navigate the file share in an iframe while on your SharePoint site. Then there is no need to have to try and link documents in SharePoint to a file share location.

Comment: Thanks..I need to do this in WCF using Client Object Model programmatically so i cannot use webpart